# How compare all input values on the Laravel validator rules?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 10 selects and I need to check if one of them have different value of 'none'. How I can write this with Laravel Validator?

Comment: Can you show us your code? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest way to achieve what you describe is :

```php
$array = [...]; // Your values
$haveDifferent = false;
foreach($array as $validate) {
    if($validate != "none") {
        $haveDifferent = true;
    }
}
// Then you can use $haveDifferent to check if there is a different value than 'none'
```

This solution is prettier than doing

```php
$input = $request->validate([
    'field1' => 'required|in:none',
    'field2' => 'required|in:none',
    'field3' => 'required|in:none',
    ...
]);
```

### Edit :

If you really need validator you could make something like :

```php
$array = [...]; // Your values
$arrayToValidate = [];
foreach($array as $selectID => $validate) {
    if($validate != "none") {
        $arrayToValidate[$selectID] = 'required|in:none';
    }
}

$input = $request->validate($arrayToValidate);
```